# How can I find my alias for `git log`?

Tags: git, bash, git-log

I have my git log formatted a specific way, which works when I call `git lg` (note the lack of an o) and it looks quite nice. I got it from a stackoverflow answer and all I had to do was enter something in the command line, like `git config ...` or something, and voila, git lg worked.

However, I'm on a new computer now and I want that to work again. How do I get what git lg is mapped to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will output the alias: `git config alias.lg`

In general, you can get at an alias with `git config alias.<alias>`. You could also look in the `.gitconfig` file and copy its contents, although the `git config` command is probably easier.

Also, I strongly suspect this was your [alias](http://ncona.com/2011/07/getting-more-from-git-log/). The original is [here](http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/pimping-out-git-log) but is throwing a 500 error for me right now (archived on [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20130116170936/http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/pimping-out-git-log)) . For folks to lazy to click the links:

```
log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```